# Test IE6 on Mac OS X

Tags: internet-explorer

I like to be able to fully test compatibility of my web pages on Mac OS X. I have installed Parallels desktop. It works fine, but it uses a lot a of resources...

So I would like to be able to test everything inside OS X. In fact I am looking for Explorer 6 for the Mac.

Any suggestions around?

Comment: http://www.kronenberg.org/ies4osx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ie net render 0.9, firefox addon... make the page on remote computer, and show you as an image what it will look like... my #1 solution right now

Comment: Not exactly sure why this answer was voted down. Yes, it's simplistic, but it's free, it does what it claims, and it does not kernel panic my Mac like the current version of WineBottler.

Answer (score 9):

IE 6 was never written for the Mac.

You might try VMWare Fusion instead of Parallels; you might have better results with resource usage.

The other solution, as other posters will indicate, is to run IE on OS X via Wine.  However, IE 6 on Wine is nothing like guaranteed to be the same as running it on Windows via a VM (VMWare or Parallels).  The Wine Apps DB lists IE 6 at the Bronze level (lowest level) of compatibility for Wine.  This may not be how you want to validate your application on the IE platform.

Comment: Parallels 4 is a major improvement over 3, but VMWare is a better choice. The last IE was 5.

Comment: unless he needs to check if people using IE via wine on OS X can properly use his website :)

Comment: The last IE was 5, but IE5 Mac was an entirely different browser from any IE for windows.  So it doesn't even give you IE5/IE5.5 Windows testing capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a tool like BrowserShots (browsershots.org). I find it to be superb for basic compatibility testing. You don't need to install anything on your machine, and you can get on with something else while you wait for your screenshots to download.

Downside is you can't use it for full web application testing, but from your original question, I don't think you need this.

Answer (score 3):

I use VirtualBox with valid MS vhd images. It is by far the best solution I've used. Follow [this screencast](http://www.10voltmedia.com/blog/2008/12/screencast-install-internet-explorer-on-osx-using-virtualbox/) to get up and running properly.

Comment: yeah this is what I use... although I got tired of having to redownload the vhd images every 3 months and installed a spare copy of windows and grabbed the Internet Explorer Collection to have IE6/7/8 all on one installation.

Comment: this would be the ideal solution but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work anymore due to windows needing to be activated on the new vhd images Microsoft provides. I would love for someone to come in and prove me wrong though...

Answer (score 3):

IE Mac PRO may help you, see http://www.ie-mac.com/ . It allows you to use the Internet Explorer 6 you asked for, and also 7, 8 and 9 on your Mac, without a VM or using a lot of resources. It needs an internet connection though, because it IE is provided via RDP.

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Browser Lab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/) lets you test your design in a large variety of browsers, and different platforms. Browser Lab returns an image of how your site is going to look in the chosen browser.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the microsoft vhd image under virtualbox, but it wanted me to register and the registration system claimed that it had a bad windows id or something. If you want to try it, you can download the vhd from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

and virtual box from www.virtualbox.org .

It loads and runs the vhd unmodified, but you run into problems the first time you reboot.

Comment: This has worked or me on Lion.  You'll need wine to extract the vhd, which you'll need to mount IDE (instead of the default SATA) to avoid the blue screen of death.  You can just ignore the registration popups, they won't stop you from testing.

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop Connection can be a light way to do that, it is not need to run a virtual machine, but a extra pc is needed.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/news/49
"full Mac OS X support"

Comment: IE 6 on Wine is nothing like guaranteed to be the same as running it on Windows.  FWIW, IE 6 is listed at the Bronze level (lowest level) of compatibility for Wine.  This may not be how you want to validate your application.

Comment: Doesn't it render HTML and execute JS same way as on Windows? Have you got some link where differences are described?

Comment: The point is the answer to that question is not knowable, except by running into the potential problem.  When basic tasks like favorites and history don't work, that's a red flag.  But the asker was clearly not looking for a correct solution, just a good enough solution so I guess the point is moot.

Comment: Correct solution? He wants to check page's compatibility with IE6, not use IE6 as his preferred browser.

Comment: He wants to test on "IE 6 used by everyone else" but will instead test on "IE 6 on Wine".  If the two are not equivalent (which is not in dispute), then he is not testing his page against the correct browser.  Hence, his solution is not correct, albeit "good enough."

Answer (score 0):

I have found crossover mac http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxmac/ to be very easy to use, and they have a 30 day free trial.