# How to test on IE while developing with OS X?

Tags: internet-explorer, macos, testing

I'm trying to get my head around how I can test that web apps work on Internet Explorer while developing with OS X.

The following criteria are all important:

- I need to be able test IE6, 7, 8 and 9
- Cost (I want to keep my costs to a minimum)
- Legality (but I don't want to violate any software licenses - from what I can tell I'm going to have to buy at least one Windows license)
- Reliability (i.e. I want to run a "real" Windows/IE instance, not something like [ies4linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page), etc.)
- Need to run each IE instance of long periods of time (so a shared instance might not be a workable solution)

If Virtual PC was still available for the Mac then the [VPC images supplied by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) would be exactly the solution I was after, but obviously without being able to run Virtual PC I can run these images.

*Update:* I am wondering if my best option is a Windows 7 Netbook + a USB KVM switch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test IE6 on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586980/test-ie6-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Re: your netbook suggestion - will it be capable of running a Windows VM, let alone 3 of them?

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to run the Real Thing (tm) in a VM such as [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/), [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com), or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org). Google around a bit - I *think* you can migrate an existing VPC image to a newer VM product.

Comment: There are instructions for migrating VPC images to VirtualBox at http://shapeshed.com/journal/testing_with_ie6_ie7_and_ie8_on_virtualbox/ but this no longer appears to work because Microsoft now require Windows activation on hardware change: http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21712